# Dudas con un datepicker que depende de otro Datepicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

tengo un problema. Tengo dos datepicker, uno que es fecha de inicio, y uno que es fecha de termino. El fecha de inicio tiene que iniciar el día que se esta creando automáticamente y eso lo he logrado hacer. Pero la fecha de termino, mi datepicker debe empezar desde la fecha de inicio que acabo de seleccionar. Es Decir son dos datapickers, uno que voy a ingresar una fecha de inicio, y el otro que voy a ingresar una fecha de termino, pero este datepicker (de la fecha de termino) debe poder solo escoger dias desde la fecha que yo he seleccionado en el datepicker anterior.

Este es mi código para la fecha de inicio:

```
dp_eveninicio.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Today;
dp_evenfinal.DisplayDateStart = ????
```

Pero el fecha termino debe empezar desde la fecha que yo soleccione en dp_eveninicio

Ayuda porfavor T-T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haría así:

```
dp_eveninicio.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Today;
dp_evenfinal.DisplayDateStart = dp_eveninicio.SelectedDate.Value;
```

Claro que deberías controlar el evento de cambio de fecha del inicio para que tu control de término se actualice automáticamente.

```
void dp_eveninicio_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dp_evenfinal.DisplayDateStart = dp_eveninicio.SelectedDate.Value;
}
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado como me dijiste tu pero añadiendole un if para que no sea nulo. Funciona, pero el problema ahora es que si por ejemplo yo pongo una fecha de inicio el 27 de julio, luego voy y pongo una fecha de termino el 29 de julio, y luego me vuelvo a la fecha de inicio y pongo el 30 de julio, y dejo la fecha de termino el 29, no me tira error. Y yo necesito que si me tire error ya que no se puede terminar un evento si nisiquiera ha empesado

Comment: Ah claro.. simplemente controla el evento SelectedDateChanged del DatPicker de término y le haces un if que verifique si la fecha es igual o mayor a la de inicio, si es pues la dejas, sino la modificas a la mínima correcta

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" 
                Loaded="datePicker_Loaded"
                DisplayDateStart="2020/01/01"
                DisplayDateEnd="2050/01/01"
                />
```

Código:

```
private void datePicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DatePicker picker = sender as DatePicker;

    if (picker.DisplayDateStart == null || picker.DisplayDateEnd == null) return;

    picker.BlackoutDates.Clear();

    DateTime start = picker.DisplayDateStart.Value;
    DateTime end = picker.DisplayDateEnd.Value;
}
```

Referencia en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15187581/3613462

Comment: Eso no es lo que estoy buscando. Necesito que mi segundo datepicker solo muestre fechas desde el dia que escogi en mi primer datepicker. Pero muchas gracias de todas maneras!